# Unique version generation from multiple versions

Tags: versioning

I'm facing a problem with the generation of a unique version ID from multiple other versions.

For example, I will take the case of a file whose version number must reflect the version of the software that was used to generate it, the version of the input data and the version of a database used to retrieve meta data constraining the content of the file.

Let's say:

```
Software   | Input    | Database  | Result file
-----------------------------------------------
3.1.0      | 2.3.9    | 3.0.9     | 01
3.1.1      | 2.3.9    | 3.0.9     | 02
3.1.1      | 2.3.9    | 3.2.0     | 03
```

where each number represents the version, and as you can see, the resulting file version must be formatted like XX, not X.Y.Z, not XXX, not X. This is a constraint.

I know that I can simply manage a table like the one above in a database or a file and when adding or changing a version, increment the resulting file version, but the program generating these versions will exist in several instances, where this table can be different. Thus, the 01 version will not be necessarily assciated to the same combination of software, input, database versions in both instances, but for readibility, it would be better in different instances to have a file version associated to a given combination across those instances.

For example:

**Instance 1**

```
Software   | Input    | Database  | Result file
-----------------------------------------------
3.1.0      | 2.3.9    | 3.0.9     | 01
3.1.1      | 2.3.9    | 3.0.9     | 02
3.1.1      | 2.3.9    | 3.2.0     | 03
```

**Instance 2**

```
Software   | Input    | Database  | Result file
-----------------------------------------------
3.1.0      | 2.3.9    | 3.0.9     | 01
3.1.1      | 2.3.9    | 3.2.0     | 02
3.1.1      | 2.5.0    | 3.2.0     | 03
```

the combination (3.1.1, 2.3.9, 3.2.0) does not have the same version for the resulting file in both instances. **Edit:** I want it to be the same in both instances, I wasn't clear enough before.

The number of combinations across instances will never exceed 100.

I was hoping for something like an hash with constraints that can result in something like this, but didn't find anything. If someone have found a solution to a similar problem...

Thanks !

Comment: How many instances of 'program generating these versions' are there going to be?

Comment: No more than two or three. And no communication between these instances is possible. So if a table needs to be shared across them, a delay can apply since it must be done manually, by "physically" putting the table somewhere for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

For small number of non-connected 'identity centers' - just partition numbers that can be issued by each center.

For example for two: one issues `2*n`, the other `2*n+1` and numbers will be unique (just remember to check that each does not issue more than 49)

Comment: Yes, but this way, there is still the possibility that a same combination of versions in both instances gives different version for the resulting file. In fact I would like to be able to associate a resulting file version to a given combination of versions of software, data, etc. But without communication between instances, it's pretty hard given the constraints...

Comment: Edited question for clarity.